# maven profile question

Tags: maven, m2eclipse

I am new to Maven and I have very basic question. I have one J2EE app(EAR). When I build this app I want to ignore some dependency in lib folder of my war as this jars will be provided by my server like jboss(all hibernate stuff). But when I run this war project inside embedded jetty server then I need it to be inside my lib folder. I heard about the maven profile which can be used for similar purpose. Can somebody give me an example or some detail about it or is there some other way to achieve this task. I have an EAR which contains ejb module(jar) and web module(war).

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Specify your library in a profile. Set `<scope>provided</scope>` for your library in a jboss profile. E.g.:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>jboss</id>
        …
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                      <groupid>...</groupid>
                      <artifactid>...</artifactid>
                      <version>...</version>
                      <scope>provided</scope>
                </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        …
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>jetty</id>
        …
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                      <groupid>...</groupid>
                      <artifactid>...</artifactid>
                      <version>...</version>
                </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        …
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Comment: Thanks this looks like a good start for me. One more question, can I also tell maven to use diff. applicationContext for jboss and jetty. If yes then how? Soryy for asking such silly question but I am total new and there not really good book available for Maven

Comment: I mean I have two applicationContext each for jboss and jetty. When I run my project on jetty during devlopment, I want spring to start transaction and when i deploy my project then it use jndi entitymanager and transaction manager from jboss. I know this is not a good design but I cant change it now at this stage as I am working on someone else code.

Comment: You can use Maven filtering (http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html). It's a property setup. You specify properties in your pom.xml, targeted files and maven sets them while build. You can set properties for each profile.

Comment: Yes, I found this in one of the blog and it rocks. Thanks for all your help and advice. I create sample project and works great